# LKMを用いたシステムコールのフックについて

Tags: linux, c

## したいこと

特定のシステムコールの引数（中身）をログとして記録したいです。

```
writev(1, [{iov_base="l", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
```

## 躓いているところ

フックしたいシステムコールはわかっていますが、それに必要なヘッダだったり、コードの書き方がわからないです。

以下のコードを参考に書いていますが、そもそも以下のコード(パケットキャプチャのコード)自体も、変数がきちんと定義されていないというエラーが出ており、お手上げ状態です。

[Linuxカーネルを読解してパケットキャプチャツールを作ろう！カーネルモジュール開発入門！](https://nttdocomo-developers.jp/entry/202212251200)

## やったこと

[第3回 侵入者の不利な情報を隠すLKM rootkitの仕組み](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/fsecurity/rensai/rootkit03/rootkit02.html)

unameシステムコールをフックする方法も試しましたが、.oファイルはinsmodできないのと、makefileを書いてみましたが、

```
 fatal error: sys/syscall.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <sys/syscall.h>
```

と出てきます。 unistd.hに変更してもダメでした。

## 教えてほしいこと

LKMでシステムコールのフックはできるのでしょうか？
他に、システムコールの内容を盗み見できる手法(ptraceは知っています)はないのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「教えてほしいこと」への回答ではないですが、（Linuxにおいては）[syscall(2)はglibcの拡張なので](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592825/4955179)libc-devのインストールが必要なようですが、インストールされていますか？

Comment: インストールしてあります。

```

linux-libc-dev is already the newest version (5.15.0-79.86).
linux-libc-dev set to manually installed.
```

Comment: linux-libc-devではなくて、libc6-dev（6の部分は何かのバージョン？）の方です。

Comment: 失礼しました。
apt list --installed | grep libc |  grep dev

libc6-dev/jammy-updates,now 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

入ってはいるようです。

Comment: もしかして、`/usr/include/sys/syscall.h`ではなくて`/usr/include/syscall.h`に入ってますか？`find /usr/include -name 'syscall.h'`してみてください。

Comment: kernel モジュールでフックしたいのであれば、kpatch, ksplice という同様の仕組みがありますので、そちらを調べてみては？
ただ、いまどきは eBPF でできるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: find /usr/include -name 'syscall.h'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/syscall.h
/usr/include/syscall.h

おっしゃる通りでした。。。

Comment: kpatch調べてみます。
eBPFも挑戦したいです。　少ないリソースでもeBPFは動きますかね、、？ @TaichiYanagiya

Comment: @alpha find /usr/include -name syscall.h
     
/usr/include/sys/syscall.h

    変更しましたが、

fatal error: sys/syscall.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <sys/syscall.h>

このようなエラーが出て今います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LKMでシステムコールのフックはできます。
実例だと、ウイルス対策ソフトがI/O系のシステムコールをフックして監視や検疫を行なっています。

＃フックの方法は、コメント欄に記述があるので割愛します。

---

LKMの参照記事がかなり古い(2003年)ので、最新の情報を参照することをお勧めします。
ディストリビューションによって、準備の手順に差異はあると思いますが、ビルドの手順は以下の通りと思います。(RHEL8の文書)

> カスタムカーネルモジュールのコンパイル
>
> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/proc_compiling-custom-kernel-modules_managing-kernel-modules

＃最新のLinuxだと、`make modules`でビルドして、`.ko`ファイルを作成する必要があるかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

頑張ってやってみます。！